# Avoid caching redirect from Special:Random in varnish

Tags: mediawiki, varnish

I'm using varnish to serve content from my MediaWiki installation to my users. Nearly every page is cached correctly, as defined in the vcl:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "xxxx";
    .port = "xxxx";
}

backend thumbor {
    .host = "xxxx";
    .port = "xxxx";
}

acl purge {
    "xxxx";
}

sub vcl_recv {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
        set req.backend_hint= default;

        if (req.method == "PURGE") {
            if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                return (synth(405, "Not allowed."));
            } else {
                return (purge);
            }
        }

        if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD" &&
            req.method != "PUT" && req.method != "POST" &&
            req.method != "TRACE" && req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
            req.method != "DELETE") {
                return (pipe);
        }

        if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
            return (pass);
        }

    if (req.http.If-None-Match) {
        return (pass);
    }

    if (req.http.X-Debug-Server) {
        return (pass);
    }

    if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache") {
        ban(req.url);
    }

        if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
          if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "MSIE 6") {
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
          } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
          } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
          } else {
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
          }
        }

    if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png)$" && req.url ~ "(?i)/thumb/" && req.http.Accept ~ "(?i)image/webp" && req.http.x-no-thumbor != "yes") {
        set req.http.x-orig-url = req.url;
        set req.url = regsub(req.url,".*\/thumb\/(.*)","/unsafe/filters:format(webp)/thumb/\1");
        set req.backend_hint = thumbor;
    }

    if (req.url ~ "action=amp$") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
        unset req.http.x-wap;
        return (hash);
    }

        if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie ~ "session" || req.http.Cookie ~ "Token") {
            return (pass);
        }

    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "droidwikiwikicookiewarning_dismissed=true") {
        set req.http.Cookie = "droidwikiwikicookiewarning_dismissed=true";
    } else {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    unset req.http.x-wap;
    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)^(lg-|sie-|nec-|lge-|sgh-|pg-)|(mobi|240x240|240x320|320x320|alcatel|android|audiovox|bada|benq|blackberry|cdm-|compal-|docomo|ericsson|hiptop|htc[-_]|huawei|ipod|kddi-|kindle|meego|midp|mitsu|mmp\/|mot-|motor|ngm_|nintendo|opera.m|palm|panasonic|philips|phone|playstation|portalmmm|sagem-|samsung|sanyo|sec-|sendo|sharp|softbank|symbian|teleca|up.browser|webos)" && req.url !~ "(\?|&)(action=amp)") {
        set req.http.x-wap = "no";
    }

    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "mf_useformat=") {
        set req.http.x-wap = "no";
    }

        return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.http.x-wap);
}

sub vcl_pipe {
        set req.http.connection = "close";
}

sub vcl_purge {
    if (req.url !~ "(\?|&)(action=amp)") {
        set req.http.X-Original = req.url;
        if (req.url ~ "&") {
            set req.url = req.url + "&action=amp";
        } else {
            set req.url = req.url + "?action=amp";
        }
        return (restart);
    }

    if (req.http.X-Original) {
        set req.url = req.http.X-Original;
    }

    if (!req.http.x-wap) {
        set req.http.x-wap = "no";
        return (restart);
    }
}

sub vcl_hit {
        if (req.method == "PURGE") {
            ban(req.url);
            return (synth(200, "Purged"));
        }

        if (!obj.ttl > 0s) {
            return (pass);
        }
}

sub vcl_miss {
        if (req.method == "PURGE")  {
            return (synth(200, "Not in cache"));
        }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.x-origin == "thumbor" && resp.status != 200) {
        set req.url = req.http.x-orig-url;
        set req.http.x-no-thumbor = "yes";
        return (restart);
    }

    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_error {
    set beresp.http.x-origin = beresp.backend.name;
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
        set beresp.grace = 120s;

        if (beresp.ttl < 48h) {
          set beresp.ttl = 48h;
        }       

        if (!beresp.ttl > 0s) {
          set beresp.uncacheable = true;
          return (deliver);
        }

        if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
          set beresp.uncacheable = true;
          return (deliver);
        }

        if (beresp.http.Authorization && !beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "public") {
          set beresp.uncacheable = true;
          return (deliver);
        }

        return (deliver);
}
```

However, the current configuration also results in redirects being cached. While this is a totally expected behaviour for usual redirecting pages (like article A redirecting to article B), it's unexpected for the `Special:Random` page. This page is expected to direct me to a random page on each time I open it. However, as the redirect is cached by varnish, I get redirected to the same page always.

What I thought about already:
1. Not caching 302 redirects at all, however, this might have negative impact to other redirects, which I usually would like to being cached
2. Having an url filter on `Special:Random`, however, doing this I would be required to do this excemption for all languages the wiki supports, in order to have it reliable. I'm not very happy about this

My question here would now be: Does anyone has an idea how this can be achieved with a rule, that doesn't need maintenance and also only covers `Special:Random`? Maybe a solution, which is also used by Wikimedia wikis? There, the `Special:Random` page redirects to always another page, however, I wasn't able to find the code block that achieves that in their code repo :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varnish respects the conventional `Cache-Control` HTTP response header that can be sent from your application.

I'm no MediaWiki expert, but I noticed [MediaWiki provides hooks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks) to extends its behavior. If you can hook into the request/response flow of MediaWiki and detect the `Special:Random` case, you might be able to inject a `Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store` header that forces Varnish not to cache these pages.

This would be an ideal way of getting expected result, without having to write VCL.

In general it is good practice to leverage HTTP's caching headers to control the behavior of a reverse caching proxy like Varnish.

- It makes the application more portable
- It makes the application less dependent on specific caching technology
- It empowers developers to think about caching from within the architecture of the application